# How to increase debugger- hover font size in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, font-size, visual-studio-debugging

Please see the following image

[image: screenshot]

The project is currently running in Visual Studio and debugger point has been hit. When I hover over "IDs", it shows a pop up(in black). I want to increase its font size.

I've tried several options in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors, but couldn't get it to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there:

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Show Settings for -> **Data Tips**

(requires restart of Visual Studio to take effect)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Fonts and Color --> Show settings for: --> Editor Tooltip.

(Not required to restart the Visual Studio)

[image]